# Perform update operation in bigQuery through PHP

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am integrating a bigQuery in my Google Cloud project. I have settle up all the requirements which required to integrate the big query. Now I want to perform the update operation through my PHP file. I have created a dataset and table in bigQuery.

- Dataset Name - count
- Table name - companies

I want to update in this table through my PHP file. Before this, here is my code for updating the values in cloud datastore:

```
$dataset = $bigQuery->dataset('count'); 
$table =  $dataset->table('companies');

if ($check) {

    $updateResponse = $table->update(['name' => 'A friendly name.']);
    if ($updateResponse->isSuccessful()) {
        print('Data updated into BigQuery successfully' . PHP_EOL);
    }  

}
```

But this code is not working ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly is your question?

Comment: `name` seems to be a label which is metadata, but `Data inserted into BigQuery successfully` is a message that suggests some data should be inserted into the table. These are two different things, so, can you clarify what exactly you want to accomplish, an example of the final state of the table will help us to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be ok, but name is not a valid metadata. `friendlyName` is a valid one, check other [table metadata resources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#resource). I'm not quite sure if `isSuccessful` exists, so, to verify whether the operation was successful or not, I would apply:

```
$info = $table->info();
echo $info['friendlyName'];
```

If you want to update data in the BigQuery table, you can execute DML statements just as you would a SELECT statement:

```
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient(['projectId' => $projectId,]);
$query = 'UPDATE statement';
$jobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query);
$job = $bigQuery->startQuery($jobConfig);
```

In this case you can ask the progress of the DML operation with `$job->isComplete()`, see the complete example [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-php).

You mentioned that "`... updating the values in cloud datastore`"; however, your code is for BigQuery, if there is something related to datastore, please clarify.